# Finding all subgroups of particular order in a group

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

I have a group order 36 inside $S_6$. I want to find all its subgroups of order 6 upto conjugation. Is there any online tool to do it?

Comment: The online tool that I pointed to in your last question also lists the conjugacy classes of subgroups, in ascending order. After you put in the generators for your permutation group and click "OK", click "Conjugacy classes of subgroups".

Comment: I did that and in the list I got two copy of Dihedral groups which are not conjugate. But how can I conclude that it does not have any other order 6 non conjugate?

Comment: Well, that's an entirely separate question! What were these two groups that were not conjugate? What was the $36$ element subgroup? One thing you could do is manually compute all the conjugates of one subgroup, and verify that it never comes to the other subgroup.